# Understanding Columns and Rows operations in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Pandas dataframe operations are pretty straightforward. Look at this, I create a datframe with two rows called A and B:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [True, False], "B": [1, 0]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
       A  B
0   True  1
1  False  0
    
In [5]: df.any()
Out[5]: 
A    True
B    True
dtype: bool
```

Documentation says operation happens on rows by default. Then how come the output contains column names instead of row index? Should not this be the output:

```
In [5]: df.any()
Out[5]: 
0    True
1    False
```

Thanks to @user4718221.

Explanation:
So *any()* reduces the index while *any(axis=1)* reduced the columns. Next question is: how all of this starts? What's the first step? Here is the explanation:

- any() returns whether any element is True. Kind of logical OR.

  it begins to reduce entire index to one value

  row 0 for column A is True. Logical OR succeeded, no more checks needed for column A

  row 0 for column B is 1 (which is True). Logical OR succeeded here too, no more checks needed for column B

  answer is A: True, B: True .. which is the correct answer

Comment: you can check the [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) documentation for better explanation

Comment: The examples I typed above, come from the pandas docs. I already read those. It says nothing more than "to operate on column, use axis=1".

Comment: @Arnuld can you accept my answer if its the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the documentation states

```
0 / ‘index’ : reduce the index, return a Series whose index is the original column labels.
```

The default value is 0, and what you're getting is a Series showing if there are any True or False values per column

Comment: My question was not about datafranme modification. Maybe the way I asked was wrong. I have edited it now

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: Yes, it helps. I added an explanation in the original post after I read your answer. Can you tell me if I got the process right?

Comment: @Arnuld yes, that is precisely how any() works. It reduces values across a row or a column to a list and searches if any of those values conform to a True condition. Once it finds a single value that is True, the operation stops. It's most commonly used when searching for null values or values of the datatype that is not wanted.